# Live search in Edittext Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, livesearch

Is it possible to update a String every time a user writes a single charachter in Edittext? I want to make a sort of Live Search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [`addTextChangedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) to add a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            yourString = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I'm sorry not to have enough points to "up" your answer